# How to git clone on Azure self hosted agent and powershell without creating a local repo

Tags: git, powershell, azure-pipelines

I am new with Git and would need some help.  Working on Azure pipelines, I created few PowerShell scripts, hosted in an Azure files git repo.  When the pipeline starts, on the Windows Self-hosted agent, I want a PowerShell script to download the latest version of the scripts in the git repo.

I tried:

```
E:
CD myFolder
git clone --no-checkout https://token@acme.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Project/_gits/fileRepos
```

But it only creates the _git folder and an empty structure

```
The fileRepos is structured like this: 
- fileRepos
  - Scripts
    - File 1
    - File 2
```

I don’t want to create a local repos or keep tracking of the files, I only want to download the files.
In addition on my agent, I would want this structure:

```
e:\myFolder
  - Scripts
    - File 1
    - File 2
```

Could you please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to git clone on Azure self hosted agent and powershell without creating a local repo

We could add a copy task in the pipeline to remove the `fileRepos` folder with following git clone command:

```
D:

cd myFolderTemp

git clone https://PAT@dev.azure.com/<YourOrganizationName>/<YourProject>/_git/TestSample
```

Then add copy task to copy the files from the temp folder `myFolderTemp` to `myFolder` without the `.git` folder:

[image]